# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{i}{2^i}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{i}{2^i}$.

I already have a solution of it in the book but it is long, so can anyone tell me a short solution for this?

Comment: Did you already try to look here at MSE?

Comment: thank you @DietrichBurde but is it a short solution ?

Comment: Yes, it is really short, just geometric series and a bit in addition in Andre's answer.

Comment: @hopefully Look at the last solution on that page, using differentiation. If you're familiar with calculus then that is a very short solution.

Comment: @hopefully "guess" the solution and then prove by induction (2 lines proof and you're done).